# drop entire panel id/firm if missing value for a variable in a particular year

Tags: stata

I have panel data and want to delete an entire panel id/firm if it has missing total assets (at) in the year 1993. Could someone help me?

So to be clear the panel data contains the following variables:

1) year: fiscal year

2) gvkey: firm id

2) at: total assets

Comment: You should at least attempt code.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this (untested, no sample data was presented) code may help.

```
// flag for non-missing non-zero assets in 1993
generate flag = year==1993 & at<. & at>0
by gvkey (year), sort: egen tokeep = max(flag)
keep if tokeep
drop flag tokeep
```

Comment: Essentially the same question from "Roy Student" within http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1322844-drop-values-in-between-a-range